# iOS Development 2 different companies 2 different developer licenses, 1 developer

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I have an iOS development License through the company I work for.  I also, have a completely separate personal iOS Development License for things I do on the side.  Can I have profiles and certificates for development and deployment to the app store for both of these licenses together on the same MAC?  How is this accomplished?  How do I assure that I don't get the profiles switched when deploying to the app store?

Thanks,
Curtis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, that scenario is quite common.

Just have both installed in your Mac, and change them from the properties of your project every time you create a new project. Every project will be linked to the specific certificate.

To change it, just click on your project, then Build settings, and set it here:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the property in Xcode.  It would a long way to making this answer really great.